# Failed to deployed In Lwc component in Org

Tags: lightning-web-components

Showing Error while deploying the source code" No module name markup".

Comment: You've given us very little information, which makes it very difficult to know what your issue might be or what the solution is. 99% of the answers you'd get (sfdcfox nonwithstanding) based on this would be essentially "shots in the dark". In general, you need to give us more information. The more details you can provide, the better.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup has a typo in it.

```
<template> 
  <!-- was misspelled as lighning -->
  <lightning-card title="Child Component"> 
    <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium"> 
      <h1>Hello From Child Component</h1> 
    </div> 
  </lightning-card> 
</template>
```

Comment: i have content on child component<template>
  <lighning-card title="Child Component">
    <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
      <h1>Hello From Child Component</h1>  
    </div>
  </lighning-card>  
</template>

Comment: @SkZunaidBinAsfar If that's what you have, verbatim, you have a problem with the markup. `lighning` should be `lightning`. I'll have to edit this answer.